# Acessing Google Calendar API from Windows Service

Tags: vb.net, google-api, windows-services, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am writing a windows service application in Visual Studio (VB) that polls a users google calendar for any events that are happening within the next 5 minutes.

Ideally, I'd like my service to generate the credentials, but I don't think a windows service can pop up a browser page to authenticate someone.  Currently I am generating the credentials in a specific location from a console app that can pop up a browser, and having the service look for credentials in that location.  I'd like to get rid of the console app altogether, but if it's necessary I'll just run it in the batch file that installs the service.

The big issue I'm having is generating the credentials file (secondary concern), and more importantly refreshing it so it doesn't expire after an hour (primary concern).

Here is my windows service code (this works perfectly fine for the hour after I run my console app and allow access to my calendar):

```
Dim Scopes As String() = {CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly}
Dim ApplicationName As String = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart"

Private Sub writeUpdateTimerEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)

    Dim credential As UserCredential

    Try

        Using stream = New FileStream("FILE PATH TO client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

            Dim credPath As String = "FILE PATH TO WHERE MY CONSOLE APP IS STORING THE CREDENTIALS FILE"
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json")

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(credPath, True)).Result

            If credential Is Nothing Then
                credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None)
            End If

        End Using

        ' Create Google Calendar API service.
        Dim service = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
            .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            .ApplicationName = ApplicationName
        })

        ' Define parameters of request.
        Dim request As EventsResource.ListRequest = service.Events.List("primary")
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now
        request.TimeMax = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
        request.ShowDeleted = False
        request.SingleEvents = True
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime

        ' List events.
        Dim eventsString As String = ""
        Dim events As Events = request.Execute()

        If events.Items IsNot Nothing AndAlso events.Items.Count > 0 Then
            'This is where I do my operations on events occuring in the next 5 minutes
            EventLog1.WriteEntry("Event occuring within 5 minutes")
        Else
            EventLog1.WriteEntry("No event occuring within 5 minutes")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        EventLog1.WriteEntry("error grabbing events." & Environment.NewLine & ex.message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is my console app code (pretty much the same as above):

```
Module Module1

Dim Scopes As String() = {CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly}
Dim ApplicationName As String = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart"

Sub Main()
    Dim credential As UserCredential

    Using stream = New FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim credPath As String = "SAME FILE PATH AS IN MY SERVICE"
        credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json")

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(credPath, True)).Result
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString("Credential file saved to: ") & credPath)
    End Using

    ' Create Google Calendar API service.
    Dim service = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
            .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            .ApplicationName = ApplicationName
        })

    ' Define parameters of request.
    Dim request As EventsResource.ListRequest = service.Events.List("primary")
    request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now
    request.ShowDeleted = False
    request.SingleEvents = True
    request.MaxResults = 10
    request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime

    ' List events.
    Dim events As Events = request.Execute()
    Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:")
    If events.Items IsNot Nothing AndAlso events.Items.Count > 0 Then
        For Each eventItem As Object In events.Items
            Dim [when] As String = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString()
            If [String].IsNullOrEmpty([when]) Then
                [when] = eventItem.Start.[Date]
            End If
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, [when])
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("You may now close this window.")
        System.Environment.Exit(0)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.")
    End If
    Console.Read()

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but have you checked [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) ?

Comment: Following the .NET Quickstart is what got me to this point, my code is basically straight from that guide, converted from CSharp to VB.

Comment: I believe you should be using a Service Account.  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount

Comment: Yeah, I realized this last night and have been setting it up today

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now, using a service account instead of a user account.  No need for dealing with generating credentials or refreshing the token.

```
Dim serviceAccountEmail As [String] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ServiceAcct")

Dim certificate = New X509Certificate2("key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)


Dim credential1 As New ServiceAccountCredential(New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) With {
        .Scopes = Scopes
    }.FromCertificate(certificate))


Dim service = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
        .HttpClientInitializer = credential1,
        .ApplicationName = ApplicationName
    })
```